# Is the use of auxiliary verb 'has' correct in this sentence?

Tags: plural-forms

Those years has taught me a little.

Some said that has is correct if you consider all those years as one unit.But, some are saying that there should be have as 'those years' is a plural form.

Comment: What would that *one unit* be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's true that noun phrases involving such things as years and money can use a singular verb (has, is), it is unlikely in standard English to be used in the case you ask about. And the reason is

> ?? Those years has taught me a little.

sounds glaringly wrong and terrible.

So I would not say *has* but *have*.

On the other hand, similar expressions can take *has* for the reason you mention: the time span is considered as one unit:

> Five years has taught me a little.

and possibly

> ? Those last five years has taught me a little.

(Not everyone may agree with me that this second one  sounds at least marginally acceptable.) But  your sentence does not sound at all acceptable to me. The only reason I can give is because the phrase *those years*,  while it could refer to a certain set of years we are familiar with, this is not enough to license (or allow) *has* since the number of years is not explicitly stated.

As for money  consider

> ?? Those  dollars has gotten me through the week.

which also sounds very questionable to me as to its acceptability as being grammatical; whereas the following is grammatical:

> Fifteen    dollars has gotten me through the week.

yet

> ? Those fifteen dollars has gotten me through the week.

sounds at least a little  strange and is, therefore, not likely to be judged by everyone as grammatical. We would likely go ahead and use the singular *that*:

> That fifteen dollars has gotten me through the week.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir. But, I need some more help. I understood that has should be used only when we mention the number. But, is it correct to use has in the following context?.
 "I spent the past 10 years horribly. Those years has taught me some". 
In the above context, 'those' means 10. So, is it correct to use?

Comment: No, use *Those years **have** taught me*.

Answer (score -1):

"have" is common use in this case. "has" is not used by native English speakers.

Both reasons are valid, in my opinion, but "has" is never used in this case. Which one is "correct" is often a matter of custom or habit, rather than logic!

Similar is the use of "data," which is a plural. When I was young it was described as a group noun, as if it were singular : "the data shows that..." But nowadays it is more common to describe it as a plural noun and say "the data show that..."

Comment: It's not that "have" is "common" here; it's that "has" is just plain wrong! The verb form of _have_ for the third person plural is **have.** At a minimum, to learn to speak and understand English, one must be able to conjugate the verbs [to be](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/be)  and [to have.](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/have)